# UICollectionViewCell Segue to new ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, segue, uicollectionviewcell

I am attempting to segue from a UICollectionViewCell to a new ViewController. I have created a segue from one ViewController to the other and created the code below for when I select the cell.

```
class FilmsViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, 
UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, 
UISearchBarDelegate {

var films: [NSDictionary]?
var filteredFilms: [NSDictionary]?

let searchBar = UISearchBar()

//let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

@IBOutlet var filmsTable: UICollectionView!

@IBOutlet var navLogo: UINavigationItem!

@IBOutlet var search: UIBarButtonItem!
@IBOutlet var back: UIBarButtonItem!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    self.filmsTable.dataSource = self
    self.filmsTable.delegate = self

    loadFilms()

}

func collectionView(_ _collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return filteredFilms?.count ?? 0

}

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = filmsTable.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "filmCell", for: indexPath) as! FilmCell

            let film = filteredFilms![indexPath.row]
            let title = film["title"] as! String

            cell.titleLabel.text = title


        return cell
    }



func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let film = filteredFilms![indexPath.row]
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "detailsSegue", sender: film)

}
```

The problem is nothing happens when I select the cell. There is no error just no response to clicking in any of the cells. I believe the issue is the cell is not responding to being clicked but I am not sure why.

EDIT: I have also tried:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "detailsSegue", sender: FilmCell)

}
```

With FilmCell being the UICollectionViewCell

FilmCell Class:

```
class FilmCell: UICollectionViewCell {


@IBOutlet var posterImage: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet var titleLabel: UILabel!

override func awakeFromNib() {

}

}
```

Comment: Are you sure your segue identifier is set to "detailsSegue" in the storyboard? and the sender in your case should be self not film and not FilmCell

Comment: It is not working with self either. The cells don't seem to be responding to the touch at all. I have also tried setting the segue from both the ViewController and from the Cell.

Comment: The segue identifier in the storyboard. Is it set? The sender will still work if you set to the cell or film. It is just bad practice

Comment: Just set a `print("hello! just didSelectItemAt !")` in the func and see if that pops up in your logs. That way we won't all be having to guess if you set your delegate or ...

Comment: @GaloTorresSevilla Yes it is set to "detailsSegue".

Comment: @Barns Nothing prints to console when I touch a cell. I have the UICollectionView delegate and datasource set both in class and viewdidload.

Comment: @Barns It's posted

Comment: I do not see that you have registered the cells for the `UICollectionView`

Comment: @Barns I've updated again with the rest of the collectionView code. FilmCell is a separate ViewCellController. All I have on it is the cells content, formatting, and sizing. If it's any help, the cells are displaying all the content. They just aren't selecting.

Comment: Error, hmmm...Apparently you do not need to register the cell if you add the cell per storyboard--sorry. I can't see what is missing. Good Luck.

Comment: Are you sure the identifier is the same (including the whether it is uppercase, lower case or camel case? ) also, try reconnecting the segue (by deleting it and adding it again) from the cell to the view controller you wish to push. When you name the segues identifier, copy paste it.

Comment: @NitinAlabur I always copy and past the identifier. I have tried connecting the segue from the cell and the viewcontroller

Comment: Welcome to SO. It's not a good practice to add 'SOLVED' into the title. Can you remove the answer from your question and accept an answer or add your own answer and then accept that? Let your question be about all your errors and failed attempts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a UITapGesture used for resigning the keyboard connected to the collection view. I was more than 100% certain I had already tried deleting the gesture and the code for it. Apparently I had not deleted it fully because I went back and tried again and this solved the issue. Tap Gestures inside of collection views sit over the cells causing them not to be selected on touch.

The solution was, DO NOT have a UITapGesture in your UICollectionView.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

             performSegue(withIdentifier: "detailsSegue", sender: nil)
    }
```

Comment: Tried this, same result. The problem defiantly seems to be that the collectionview or the cell is not responding to touch.